# Can we specify in FxCopCmd line to use only pdb dlls?

Tags: dll, fxcop, fxcopcmd

When we run `FxCopCmd` keeping `*.dll` as the input , is there anything we can do to just run the ones with `pdb` , so that we don't get the error `Failed to Load assemblies` without the `pdb`?

**UPDATE:** It's not an error maybe because the execution continues, strangely I'm not getting Failed to Load assemblies warnings. But i get te below warnings due which the `Process.Errorcode` is not `0`
*Conflicting target platforms 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' vs 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.Conflicting target platforms 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' vs 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.Conflicting target platforms 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' vs 'mscorlib,*

Comment: You shouldn't be getting an error for this, just a warning.  Could you please paste exact output (including any error codes)?